# Angular throws an error when I have my service at a different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service like the folowing one:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.service('messagingService', function($http){

this.getMessages = function(offset, limit, successCallback, errorCallback){
// some stuff goes here
};

});
```

I include this file and afterwards I include my controller file.

My controller starts like this

```
function Inbox($scope, $http, messagingService) {

}
```

But when I load my page I get the following error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=messagingServiceProvider%20%3C-%20messagingService
    at Error ()
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6:453
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:32:320
    at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:29:461)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:32:388
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:29:461)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:30:130)
    at Object.Xb.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:31:284)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:61:304)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:48:476

When I use my service code in same file as the controller it works well. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Care attaching controller definition to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to attach your controller to your module.

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.service('messagingService', function($http){

this.getMessages = function(offset, limit, successCallback, errorCallback){
   // some stuff goes here
 };

});
app.controller('Inbox',['$scope', '$http', 'messagingService',function($scope, $http, messagingService){}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Good way is to inject the service as dependency for eg:

```
var app = angular.module('ur_app_name')
app.service('messagingService', function($http){

this.getMessages = function(offset, limit, successCallback, errorCallback){
 //some stuff goes here
};

app.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope','messagingService' function($scope,messagingService) {
 //something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.services']);
```

in your app.js

and then in your services.js

```
var services = angular.module('app.services');

services('messagingService', function($http){....
```